# Image grid with single description field, changeable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to create is a a grid of images with one single text field below the grid. That field is supposed to contain the description of whatever image has last been clicked on. I implemented the grid as a div containing several floating divs with the respective images, like this. Though I suspect the exact implementation isn't the most important part here:

HTML:

```
<div id="ingredient-showcase">
    <div class="ingredient"><img src="..." alt="..." /></div>
    <div class="ingredient"><img src="..." alt="..." /></div>
    <div class="ingredient"><img src="..." alt="..." /></div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ingredient-showcase {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%
}

.ingredient {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 170px;
    width: 170px;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

So what would be a good way to implement the dynamic description box? Will pure HTML/CSS suffice for that (I suspect not) or will javascript/jquery be required? I suppose you could simply put all the decriptions in a single box with the exact same position and then just change the respective z-indices with every click. But I'm not sure if that would be the best practice or even work out at all.

I haven't found any answer to this while browsing the web so far, so if this hasn't been answered already I hope it will also be helpful to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easy using jQuery. You could store the text to display in an element or even an `alt` or `data-` attribute on the `img` tag, then take that text and populate your div at the bottom.

```js
$('.ingredient').on('click',function() {
  $('#caption').html($(this).find('.meta').html())
})
```

```css
.meta {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ingredient-showcase">
  <div class="ingredient"><img src="..." alt="..." />
    <div class="meta">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ingredient"><img src="..." alt="..." />
    <div class="meta">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ingredient"><img src="..." alt="..." />
    <div class="meta">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the z-index thing.  Just use JavaScript or jquery to populate the box with the descriptions.  You can either pull the description from the alt tag or add a data attribute containing the description and pull it from there, like this:

```
<div id="ingredient-showcase">
    <div class="ingredient"><img src="..." data-description="..." /></div>
    ...
</div>
<div id="description"></div>
```

Now in jquery you can just do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ingredient > img').click(function () {
        $('#description').text($(this).data('description'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var TMP_IMG_URL = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634_960_720.png";

var $grid = $('#grid');
var $description = $('#description');

var columns = 3;

var items = [{
    src: TMP_IMG_URL,
    description: "Adipisicing nobis nihil et in velit minima Expedita quasi mollitia exercitationem non porro Nulla consectetur natus aspernatur officiis iure! Veritatis ullam excepturi repellendus consequuntur magni! Exercitationem laudantium praesentium sed facilis.",
    alt: "I've no idea what alt is."
  },
  {
    src: TMP_IMG_URL,
    description: "Consectetur quasi cum sit voluptates perspiciatis? Nobis aliquam corporis molestias pariatur nobis Repudiandae eaque fuga veritatis quaerat eligendi accusantium. Amet facilis quaerat nemo laboriosam aliquid? Labore eum accusantium molestiae nobis.",
    alt: "I've no idea what alt is."

  },
  {
    src: TMP_IMG_URL,
    description: "Adipisicing nobis nihil et in velit minima Expedita quasi mollitia exercitationem non porro Nulla consectetur natus aspernatur officiis iure! Veritatis ullam excepturi repellendus consequuntur magni! Exercitationem laudantium praesentium sed facilis.",
    alt: "I've no idea what alt is."

  },
  {
    src: TMP_IMG_URL,
    description: "Sit magnam nobis voluptas eos adipisci. Aspernatur neque explicabo saepe amet ad sint Ex laborum ullam veritatis obcaecati debitis Ab laudantium quo facilis delectus excepturi fugiat. Perspiciatis maiores atque saepe?",
    alt: "I've no idea what alt is."

  },
  {
    src: TMP_IMG_URL,
    description: "Consectetur non quibusdam adipisci sequi velit Voluptas architecto aliquid quis iusto fugit Voluptas porro ullam vitae quae iste, iusto? Id fugiat harum sit quis nisi eos Laborum similique id reprehenderit!",
    alt: "I've no idea what alt is."

  },
  {
    src: TMP_IMG_URL,
    description: "Sit culpa animi aperiam totam iusto odit Suscipit quia molestiae sunt amet ut Veniam fugit qui atque explicabo repellendus debitis? Libero atque in ut earum pariatur Libero nemo quae beatae?",
    alt: "I've no idea what alt is."

  }
];

$description.text(items[0].description);

var $row;
items.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (index % columns === 0) {
    $row = $('<div class="row">');
    $grid.append($row);
  }
  var $column = $('<div class="column">');
  var $img = $('<img alt="' + item.alt + '" src="' + item.src + '">');
  $column.append($img);
  $column.css({
    width: 100 / columns + '%',
    float: 'left'
  });
  $column.click(function() {
    $description.text(items[index].description);
  });
  $row.append($column);
  // console.log(index, item);
});

var $row = $('<div>');
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#over {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.grid {
  display: block;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.column {
  border: none;
  display: block;
}

.description {
  font-size: 12px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="over">
  <div id="grid" class="grid"></div>
  <div id="description" class="description"></div>
</div>

<!-- grid is gonna be like this
<div class="grid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="column"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="column"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="column"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="column"><img src="" alt=""></div>
   </div>
</div>
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with angular.js ?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('IngredientController', function($scope) {
  $scope.description = '';

  $scope.setDescription = function(description) {
    $scope.description = description;
  };

  $scope.ingredients = [{
      src: "...",
      alt: "...",
      description: "description 1"
    },
    {
      src: "...",
      alt: "...",
      description: "description 2"
    },
    {
      src: "...",
      alt: "...",
      description: "description 3"
    }
  ];
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#over {
  text-align: center;
}

#ingredient-showcase {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.ingredient {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.ingredient img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" id="over" ng-controller="IngredientController">
  <div id="ingredient-showcase">
    <div class="ingredient" ng-repeat="ingredient in ingredients" ng-click="setDescription(ingredient.description)">
      <img ng-src="{{ ingredient.src }}" alt="{{ ingredient.alt }}" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>{{ description }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#ingredient-showcase {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%
}

.ingredient {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

#description {
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <div id="ingredient-showcase">
    <div class="ingredient" ng-click="description = 'description 1'">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="ingredient" ng-click="description = 'description 2'">
      <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="ingredient" ng-click="description = 'description 3'">
      <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
  <p id="description">{{ description }}</p>
</div>
```